# drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done in syslog, laptop freezes, chromium freezes

Tags: google-chrome, lenovo-laptop, linux-kernel, debian-stretch

My lenovo laptop running Debian sometimes spontaneously freezes, and now chrome is unusable (freezes, its window cannot be raised in the WM)

```
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329237] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329318] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 913 at /build/linux-BsFdsw/linux-4.9.65/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:14196 intel_atomic_commit_tail+0xf2b/0xf50 [i915]
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329321] pipe A vblank wait timed out
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329322] Modules linked in: ctr ccm xt_multiport iptable_filter bnep binfmt_misc iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support arc4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_conexant iwldvm snd_hda_codec_generic kvm mac80211 irqbypass intel_cstate intel_uncore intel_rapl_perf i915 evdev joydev serio_raw iwlwifi uvcvideo snd_hda_intel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_hda_codec drm_kms_helper videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_hda_core drm snd_hwdep thinkpad_acpi btusb btrtl videodev snd_pcm btbcm lpc_ich mei_me btintel sg mfd_core media cfg80211 bluetooth nvram snd_timer i2c_algo_bit mei shpchp snd soundcore wmi rfkill ac video battery button ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 jbd2 crc32c_generic fscrypto ecb mbcache algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329409]  dm_mod sd_mod crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel ahci libahci aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd libata scsi_mod psmouse ehci_pci i2c_i801 ehci_hcd i2c_smbus xhci_pci xhci_hcd sdhci_pci sdhci mmc_core e1000e usbcore ptp usb_common pps_core thermal [last unloaded: pcspkr]
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329452] CPU: 3 PID: 913 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329453] Hardware name: LENOVO 1294AA8/1294AA8, BIOS 8MET70WW (1.70 ) 07/23/2013
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329458]  0000000000000000 ffffffff98729134 ffffae7001207ad0 0000000000000000
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329464]  ffffffff98475efe 0000000000000000 ffffae7001207b28 ffff99f3cbea0000
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329469]  0000000000000000 ffff99f3cfcb8000 0000000000000001 ffffffff98475f7f
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329474] Call Trace:
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329486]  [<ffffffff98729134>] ? dump_stack+0x5c/0x78
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329492]  [<ffffffff98475efe>] ? __warn+0xbe/0xe0
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329498]  [<ffffffff98475f7f>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329503]  [<ffffffff984b7d8c>] ? finish_wait+0x3c/0x70
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329558]  [<ffffffffc0bc1e6b>] ? intel_atomic_commit_tail+0xf2b/0xf50 [i915]
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329563]  [<ffffffff984b7f90>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329610]  [<ffffffffc0bc21e5>] ? intel_atomic_commit+0x355/0x4c0 [i915]
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329632]  [<ffffffffc0a0e586>] ? drm_atomic_helper_disable_plane+0xa6/0xe0 [drm_kms_helper]
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329667]  [<ffffffffc096ad40>] ? __setplane_internal+0x220/0x270 [drm]
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329696]  [<ffffffffc0963b50>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0xa0/0xb0 [drm]
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329721]  [<ffffffffc096b903>] ? drm_mode_setplane+0x143/0x1a0 [drm]
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329744]  [<ffffffffc0950b3a>] ? drm_ioctl+0x1ea/0x470 [drm]
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329769]  [<ffffffffc096b7c0>] ? drm_plane_check_pixel_format+0x50/0x50 [drm]
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329773]  [<ffffffff984b8030>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329777]  [<ffffffff9861642f>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x9f/0x600
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329783]  [<ffffffff986042ca>] ? __fput+0x17a/0x220
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329787]  [<ffffffff9851dfad>] ? __audit_syscall_entry+0xad/0xf0
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329793]  [<ffffffff98403441>] ? syscall_trace_enter+0x1b1/0x2c0
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329796]  [<ffffffff98616a04>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x74/0x80
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329800]  [<ffffffff98403b1c>] ? do_syscall_64+0x7c/0xf0
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329807]  [<ffffffff98a076ef>] ? entry_SYSCALL64_slow_path+0x25/0x25
Mar 25 15:33:40 debian-x1 kernel: [43100.329811] ---[ end trace 56747d9e75aaddba ]---
Mar 25 15:33:51 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.493030] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557019] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557099] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 913 at /build/linux-BsFdsw/linux-4.9.65/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:14196 intel_atomic_commit_tail+0xf2b/0xf50 [i915]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557101] pipe A vblank wait timed out
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557167] Modules linked in: ctr ccm xt_multiport iptable_filter bnep binfmt_misc iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support arc4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_conexant iwldvm snd_hda_codec_generic kvm mac80211 irqbypass intel_cstate intel_uncore intel_rapl_perf i915 evdev joydev serio_raw iwlwifi uvcvideo snd_hda_intel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_hda_codec drm_kms_helper videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_hda_core drm snd_hwdep thinkpad_acpi btusb btrtl videodev snd_pcm btbcm lpc_ich mei_me btintel sg mfd_core media cfg80211 bluetooth nvram snd_timer i2c_algo_bit mei shpchp snd soundcore wmi rfkill ac video battery button ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 jbd2 crc32c_generic fscrypto ecb mbcache algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557194]  dm_mod sd_mod crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel ahci libahci aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd libata scsi_mod psmouse ehci_pci i2c_i801 ehci_hcd i2c_smbus xhci_pci xhci_hcd sdhci_pci sdhci mmc_core e1000e usbcore ptp usb_common pps_core thermal [last unloaded: pcspkr]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557200] CPU: 0 PID: 913 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557201] Hardware name: LENOVO 1294AA8/1294AA8, BIOS 8MET70WW (1.70 ) 07/23/2013
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557209]  0000000000000000 ffffffff98729134 ffffae70012078a0 0000000000000000
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557212]  ffffffff98475efe 0000000000000000 ffffae70012078f8 ffff99f3cbea0000
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557215]  0000000000000000 ffff99f3cfcb8000 0000000000000001 ffffffff98475f7f
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557217] Call Trace:
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557227]  [<ffffffff98729134>] ? dump_stack+0x5c/0x78
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557233]  [<ffffffff98475efe>] ? __warn+0xbe/0xe0
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557238]  [<ffffffff98475f7f>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557244]  [<ffffffff984b7d8c>] ? finish_wait+0x3c/0x70
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557299]  [<ffffffffc0bc1e6b>] ? intel_atomic_commit_tail+0xf2b/0xf50 [i915]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557304]  [<ffffffff984b7f90>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557349]  [<ffffffffc0bc21e5>] ? intel_atomic_commit+0x355/0x4c0 [i915]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557370]  [<ffffffffc0a107ec>] ? restore_fbdev_mode+0x14c/0x270 [drm_kms_helper]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557406]  [<ffffffffc0963b50>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0xa0/0xb0 [drm]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557421]  [<ffffffffc0a1232e>] ? drm_fb_helper_restore_fbdev_mode_unlocked+0x2e/0x70 [drm_kms_helper]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557433]  [<ffffffffc0a12399>] ? drm_fb_helper_set_par+0x29/0x50 [drm_kms_helper]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557480]  [<ffffffffc0bdbd53>] ? intel_fbdev_set_par+0x13/0x60 [i915]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557485]  [<ffffffff987a60da>] ? fb_set_var+0x20a/0x400
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557519]  [<ffffffffc066b988>] ? ext4_mark_iloc_dirty+0x528/0x7b0 [ext4]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557550]  [<ffffffffc069cf56>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x36/0x70 [ext4]
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557557]  [<ffffffff9879ca61>] ? fbcon_blank+0x2f1/0x330
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557563]  [<ffffffff98829c67>] ? do_unblank_screen+0xd7/0x1a0
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557568]  [<ffffffff98820599>] ? vt_ioctl+0x4d9/0x1260
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557574]  [<ffffffff9881509b>] ? tty_ioctl+0x33b/0xc30
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557578]  [<ffffffff9886c2d0>] ? vga_arb_release+0xb0/0x100
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557581]  [<ffffffff9861642f>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x9f/0x600
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557586]  [<ffffffff986042ca>] ? __fput+0x17a/0x220
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557591]  [<ffffffff9851dfad>] ? __audit_syscall_entry+0xad/0xf0
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557596]  [<ffffffff98403441>] ? syscall_trace_enter+0x1b1/0x2c0
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557599]  [<ffffffff98616a04>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x74/0x80
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557603]  [<ffffffff98403b1c>] ? do_syscall_64+0x7c/0xf0
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557610]  [<ffffffff98a076ef>] ? entry_SYSCALL64_slow_path+0x25/0x25
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43110.557613] ---[ end trace 56747d9e75aaddbb ]---
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43120.732621] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43130.972038] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Mar 25 15:34:21 debian-x1 kernel: [43141.210815] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Mar 25 15:34:32 debian-x1 kernel: [43151.448328] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Mar 25 15:34:42 debian-x1 kernel: [43161.686042] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Mar 25 15:36:26 debian-x1 kernel: [43265.861215] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Mar 25 15:36:36 debian-x1 kernel: [43276.099900] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.338660] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730531] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730622] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 31320 at /build/linux-BsFdsw/linux-4.9.65/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:14196 intel_atomic_commit_tail+0xf2b/0xf50 [i915]
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730625] pipe A vblank wait timed out
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730626] Modules linked in: ctr ccm xt_multiport iptable_filter bnep binfmt_misc iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support arc4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_conexant iwldvm snd_hda_codec_generic kvm mac80211 irqbypass intel_cstate intel_uncore intel_rapl_perf i915 evdev joydev serio_raw iwlwifi uvcvideo snd_hda_intel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_hda_codec drm_kms_helper videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_hda_core drm snd_hwdep thinkpad_acpi btusb btrtl videodev snd_pcm btbcm lpc_ich mei_me btintel sg mfd_core media cfg80211 bluetooth nvram snd_timer i2c_algo_bit mei shpchp snd soundcore wmi rfkill ac video battery button ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 jbd2 crc32c_generic fscrypto ecb mbcache algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730726]  dm_mod sd_mod crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel ahci libahci aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd libata scsi_mod psmouse ehci_pci i2c_i801 ehci_hcd i2c_smbus xhci_pci xhci_hcd sdhci_pci sdhci mmc_core e1000e usbcore ptp usb_common pps_core thermal [last unloaded: pcspkr]
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730775] CPU: 0 PID: 31320 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730777] Hardware name: LENOVO 1294AA8/1294AA8, BIOS 8MET70WW (1.70 ) 07/23/2013
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730781]  0000000000000000 ffffffff98729134 ffffae7009823b00 0000000000000000
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730789]  ffffffff98475efe 0000000000000000 ffffae7009823b58 ffff99f3cbea0000
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730794]  0000000000000000 ffff99f3cfcb8000 0000000000000001 ffffffff98475f7f
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730800] Call Trace:
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730814]  [<ffffffff98729134>] ? dump_stack+0x5c/0x78
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730821]  [<ffffffff98475efe>] ? __warn+0xbe/0xe0
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730827]  [<ffffffff98475f7f>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730834]  [<ffffffff984b7d8c>] ? finish_wait+0x3c/0x70
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730896]  [<ffffffffc0bc1e6b>] ? intel_atomic_commit_tail+0xf2b/0xf50 [i915]
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730902]  [<ffffffff984b7f90>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730954]  [<ffffffffc0bc21e5>] ? intel_atomic_commit+0x355/0x4c0 [i915]
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.730978]  [<ffffffffc0a0e979>] ? drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x79/0xb0 [drm_kms_helper]
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731018]  [<ffffffffc0958201>] ? drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x61/0x110 [drm]
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731048]  [<ffffffffc0959927>] ? drm_mode_setcrtc+0x3c7/0x4a0 [drm]
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731074]  [<ffffffffc0950b3a>] ? drm_ioctl+0x1ea/0x470 [drm]
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731101]  [<ffffffffc0959560>] ? drm_mode_getcrtc+0x120/0x120 [drm]
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731107]  [<ffffffff9861642f>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x9f/0x600
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731112]  [<ffffffff9851dfad>] ? __audit_syscall_entry+0xad/0xf0
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731118]  [<ffffffff98403441>] ? syscall_trace_enter+0x1b1/0x2c0
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731122]  [<ffffffff98616a04>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x74/0x80
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731126]  [<ffffffff98403b1c>] ? do_syscall_64+0x7c/0xf0
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731134]  [<ffffffff98a076ef>] ? entry_SYSCALL64_slow_path+0x25/0x25
Mar 25 15:36:47 debian-x1 kernel: [43286.731138] ---[ end trace 56747d9e75aaddbc ]---
Mar 25 15:36:57 debian-x1 kernel: [43296.833366] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Mar 25 15:41:48 debian-x1 kernel: [43588.241564] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 114525)
Mar 25 15:41:48 debian-x1 kernel: [43588.241565] CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 114525)
Mar 25 15:41:48 debian-x1 kernel: [43588.241567] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 138286)
Mar 25 15:41:48 debian-x1 kernel: [43588.241568] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 138286)
Mar 25 15:41:48 debian-x1 kernel: [43588.241569] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 138286)
Mar 25 15:41:48 debian-x1 kernel: [43588.241576] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 138286)
Mar 25 15:41:48 debian-x1 kernel: [43588.242544] CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
Mar 25 15:41:48 debian-x1 kernel: [43588.242544] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Mar 25 15:41:48 debian-x1 kernel: [43588.242545] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
```

Some of the chromium logs:

[31807:31895:0325/153734.810729:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.

```
(chromium:31807): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Unknown or unsupported transport 'disabled' for address 'disabled:'
[31807:31807:0325/155303.456402:ERROR:zygote_communication_linux.cc(309)] Failed to send GetTerminationStatus message to zygote
[31807:31807:0325/155303.460548:ERROR:zygote_communication_linux.cc(309)] Failed to send GetTerminationStatus message to zygote
[31807:31807:0325/155303.464050:ERROR:zygote_communication_linux.cc(309)] Failed to send GetTerminationStatus message to zygote
[31807:31842:0325/155303.529262:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(121)] Failed to launch GPU process.
```

$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series./C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 3e)
0d:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 07)
0f:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
```

Is this a hardware issue? How can I diagnose it and what can be done about it?

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch)

Edit: I'm able to work around the chromium freeze by invoking it with one of these flags or both: --disable-gpu-vsync --disable-gpu

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by changing my command line to add `video=SVIDEO-1:d` as described at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1689914#p1689914.